# How do I add a variable to my active session array?

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I only learn by asking.

I have a form that gathers name, address, etc.. The form was originally designed with just one field for name called `bill_name`. I have changed it to two fields `bill_fname` and `bill_lname`. The session data is then used for visual verification on the next page and then submitted for processed following that.

How do I combine the variables `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname']` and `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname']` and add them to the array as `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_name']` on the verification page before sending them to be processed?

The reason for having all 3 variables in the array is a good part of the processing code uses the `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_name']` and the new code I'm adding needs the the separate values of `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname']` and `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname']`

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simply, just concatenate the strings (i'm using a space here also) and assign them to the `bill_name` key;

```
  $_SESSION['donate']['bill_name'] = $_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname'] . " " . $_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname']
```

Also, I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with this approach. However, I'm not much a php developer so I'm not knowledgable on best practices.

Comment: So by just defining `$_SESSION['donate']['bill_name']` it will add it to the session array without destroying any of the other array variables?

Comment: It won't destroy the others, but it will add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$_SESSION['donate']['bill_name'] = $_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname']." ".$_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname'];
echo $_SESSION['donate']['bill_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want the separate parts of the name in tact:

```
$_SESSION['donate']['bill_name'] = array(
    'bill_fname' => $_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname'],
    'bill_lname' => $_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname'],
    'full_name' => $_SESSION['donate']['bill_fname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['donate']['bill_lname']
);
```